# SQLite Update not working in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've been trying to update my data in sqlite android, but it doesn't work. Also, there is also no error message shown in the logcat.

Here are my codes:

Dbadapter.java:

```
public boolean updateEntry(SalesItemInformationLV testing)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        try {

            values.put(ENTRY_NAME, testing.getItemname());
            values.put(ENTRY_TEL, testing.getCostprice());
            values.put(ENTRY_SELLINGPRICE, testing.getSellingprice());
            values.put(ENTRY_QTYSOLD, testing.getItemquantity());
            values.put(ENTRY_DATESOLD, testing.getDatesold());
            values.put(ENTRY_STAFFDISCOUNT, testing.getStaffdiscount());

        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            Log.w(MYDBADAPTER_LOG_CAT, "Update failed!" + e.toString());
        }


        // updating row
        int returnvalue =  _db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(testing.getId()) });
        return returnvalue==1 ? true : false;
    }
```

MyItems.java:

```
 public  boolean updateDatabase(SalesItemInformationLV testing2, Context c)
{
    MyDbAdapter db = new MyDbAdapter(c);
    db.open();

    boolean rowIDofUpdatedEntry = db.updateEntry(testing2);
    db.close();
    return  rowIDofUpdatedEntry;
}
```

ListView.java, which passes saleitem2 object intent to Edit.java:

```
    MyItems mi2;
 private ArrayList<SalesItemInformationLV> displayiteminfo2;
mi2 = MyItems.getInstance();
 displayiteminfo2 = mi2.retrieveAllForlist2(getApplicationContext());
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                SalesItemInformationLV saleitem2 = displayiteminfo2.get(position);
             String namevalue = saleitem2.getItemname();

            Intent myintent = new Intent(ListSaleItemActivity.this, EditSaleActivity.class);
            myintent.putExtra("array", saleitem2);             

            startActivity(myintent);
```

Edit.java which will use the update method from Items.java:

```
 Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        final SalesItemInformationLV sale1 = (SalesItemInformationLV)extras.getSerializable("array");
        final int id1 = extras.getInt("itemID");

btnSaveChanges.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

mc.updateDatabase(sale1, getApplicationContext());

}}
```

I have been trying to figure out, and I think there could be something wrong in my Dbadapter.java, but i am not sure. Please advise me on how to solve this thanks!

Comment: Sometime when my database not work i just uninstalled my app and install it again and it work's and be sure to check if SalesItemInformationLV  is not returning any null value

Comment: @Salman500 doing that will not fix the issue.. just saying;)

Comment: Odds on `testing.getId()` doesn't equate to a row's **_id**. I suggest using break points or logging to determine what values are being passed to the update. Perhaps precede the update with a query to see if a row exists that matches the selection criteria.